# Xcode: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" in GLFW / GLAD default C application

Tags: c, xcode, opengl, glfw, glad

I am a newbie in GLFW and I tried to make the most basic application with GLFW and OpenGL in C. I took the example code from GLFW documentation: https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html. It worked. However when I include GLAD at the top of my program it crashes at `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`. When code isn't running no errors appear and build succeeds. I've tried GLADs from both https://gen.glad.sh/ and http://glad.dav1d.de/. The build in both includes only GL of version 4.6, Core instead of Compatibility.

I am right now on Macbook Pro with M1 Pro, MacOS Monterey 12.0.1. Installed GLFW with `brew install`.

Screenshots:

[Xcode project setup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peLlX.png)

[Build Phases screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IglJs.png)

[Screenshot of an error while running a program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egTpu.png)

Also, I am new to Xcode as well as I have always used CLion for programming so it's possible that I messed up something while trying to setup all of this.

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code and errors. Paste the code and error trace.

Comment: glad need to be initialized with `gladLoadGLLoader`. See [Glad failing to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650497/glad-failing-to-initialize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Jowever when I include GLAD at the top of my program it crashes at `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

Because you're now calling a function at address `NULL`. What the glad header does is for every GL function name like `glClear`, it will define a *preprocessor macro* to glad's internal function pointers:

```
typedef void (GLAD_API_PTR *PFNGLCLEARPROC)(GLbitfield   mask);
GLAD_API_CALL PFNGLCLEARPROC glad_glClear;
#define glClear glad_glClear
```

You'll actually need to call `gladLoadGLLoader` to load all these function pointers at runtime, **after you created and made current the GL context** you want to work with.

Since you use GLFW, you can use `glfwGetProcAddress` directly as the _loader function:

```
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
    // error out
}
```

as it is documented in [the glad readme](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad#glad).