# EXC_BAD_ACCESS from glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw, glad

I've looked around and apparently I've got the choice between this solution, and my problem was the same as the following:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550520/xcode-thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x0-in-glfw-glad-default-c/77284851#77284851),
but I still don't know how to solve this problem.
When I use glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); in xcode, it will alarm that `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`, but when I annotate it with "//", the project will work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqy7M.png)
Thanks in advance!

I try to "//" this code, but it will not clear the window' render.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could repeat the issue with your code. I also checked the suggested solution.
you should call gladLoadGLLoader after glfwMakeContextCurrent.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        // error out
    }

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {        
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Also it was not a problem with glClear. Any OpenGL call would also cause crash if GL function pointers are not properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the GL entry points (function pointers) after setting the active context with something like:

```
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress))
    // failed to load...
```

Also, prevent system GL headers being included if using the GLAD library:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
...
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Utimately the problem has been solved! I will pay more attention to it in the future.